# KDE - Open a window in the center of the screen

Tags: shell, kde, konsole, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

Is it possible to open a window in KDE using a command line (similar to the example below) in the center of the screen? If yes, is it possible set this independently of the screen size?

Example:

```
konsole --hide-tabbar --hide-menubar -p "TerminalColumns=104;TerminalRows=25" -e 'htop'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to use the KWin facilities:

right click the title bar of your window, select More Actions > Special Window Settings > Size and Position and farkle about a bit.

For example, I bet that

> Initial Placement > Force > Centered

```
 will do exactly what you wish.
```

There probably are commands to do this from the command line, but I'll have to defer to someone else in that regard.

Cheers, Andy